# Problem with handling NULL values in an SQL procedure

Tags: sql

The following procedure should be able to handle the following action:
If the difference in records is 0, we let it pass; if there are no data or summary file, or neither - we terminate it.

However, if DIFF_RECORDS is also null when everything matches, we will then terminate the job.

How can I change the logic here to handle such a case?

Comment: Probably you should reverse the order of the expressions and remove the `else`

Comment: Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse the order of the `IF` expressions, first check for `@DIFF_RECORDS` being `NULL` and separately check the length.

```
IF @DIFF_RECORDS IS NULL
  THROW 51000, 'No fresh files to load', 0;

IF LEN(@DIFF_RECORDS) > 0
  THROW 51000, @DIFF_RECORDS, 0;
```

Comment: It won't work well because if the data is consistent, we also don't have DIFF_RECORDS and we will display 'no fresh file'